# Smoothness of functions up to the boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $R^n$ with $C^1$ boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Suppose that $f$ is a $C^1$ function on $\Omega \cup \partial \Omega $, where $C^1$-smoothness of $f(x)$ on  $\partial \Omega$ is defined via local $C^1$- diffeomorphism.

If we define a function $g$ on $\Omega$ as $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in \Omega$, and fix $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$, then is it true that $D^{\alpha} g(x) \to D^{\alpha} f(x_0)$ as $x \to x_0$ for each multiindex $|\alpha| \leq 1$?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not true, because your definition of being $C^1$ on $\Omega 
\cup \partial \Omega$ is bad.

Your definition only guarantees that the restriction of $f$ to the boundary is $C^1$, but that is not good enough: $f$ can be $C^1$ on $\Omega$ and on $\partial \Omega$ without being even continuous on $\Omega 
\cup \partial \Omega$.

You should say that $f$ is $C^1$ at points of $\partial \Omega$ if it admits a $C^1$ extension in small open sets around them. This is a good definition and it does not require $\partial \Omega$ to have any kind of regularity.

Comment: If $f$ admits a $C^1$ extension at points on $\partial \Omega$ AND if, in addition, $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$, is then my claim true?

Comment: Yes. But you do not need $\partial \Omega$ to be ${\cal C}^1$.

Comment: But if $g$ is the function on $\partial \Omega$ defined as the restriction of $u$ on the boundary, I cannot talk about $C^1$ smoothenss of $g$ on $\partial \Omega$ unless $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$ smooth because there does not necessarily exist local diffeomorphism of straghtening the boundary. I guess, what I am still not sure is that if $f$ admist  $C^1$ extension, can you say still say $f \vert_{\partial \Omega}$ is a $C^1$-function on $\partial \Omega$ if $\partial \Omega$ is not $C^1$, and if so why?

Comment: you can still say it, just by convention.